# Make a composer package for a laravel trait

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I make a Trait to make a CRUD for my websites with Laravel,
and I want to make a new package in packagist and when run "**composer install**"
put this files inside the Traits folder of my new project. 
Its possible to do that ?

[image]

Comment: That's not quite how Composer packages work. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a composer package for your Trait, but when you install it with `composer install` it will be placed inside the vendor/ folder. This should not be a problem as your projects can still refer to it by the namespace.

Before submitting the package to packagist.org you can try it out using just a git repostiory instead, to see if it actually makes sense to have this as a separate package. In order to do this, you can move your Trait and any other classes into their own library folder outside your project. Then use `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit` to create a new git repository and commit your classes that should make up your library. In order to make this a proper library that can be recognized by composer you also need a `composer.json`. The easiest way to set this up is using the command `composer init`. It will guide you through the creation of your initial `composer.json` that you can then modify later on. Commit this file as well. You might have to do add some more things like autoloading info. For this you can just look at the composer.json of other libraries and check out what they have in there. Now you can push your trait-library to Github or wherever else you want to host your git repository. You can even use a private git repository at first, if you don't want to publish your code for the whole world to see.

Now that you have published your library to github you can use it in your project. For this you have to add the git repository to your `composer.json`:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/yourusername/yourlibrary"
        }
    ]
```

If you are using a private repository, you have to use the ssh url instead, so in this case the url would be `git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/yourlibrary.git`.

This will allow composer to fetch package infos from this repository. In other words, it will read the name of your library from the `composer.json` we commited before in our separate library folder. The final step, in your project using the trait-library, you can now run `composer require <vendor>/<library>` you might also have to specify the version as `dev-master` or add an `branch-alias` to the library's (!) `composer.json` or release a version of the library on GitHub, i.e. add a version tag.

When at a later point you decide to publish your library on packagist.org, all you have to do in your project(s) is remove the custom `repository` section inside the `composer.json` and the library will be automatically picked up via packagist instead.